# Magento 2 - API to sendAccountNewEmail

Tags: magento2, email, customer-account

I created an customer account using `/V1/customers` but it does not send the new account  email.

Is there any API to do so?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any API to do so?

`/V1/customers` or `createAccount` itself has email sending functionality, make sure double check your email configurations with proper mail id.

`/V1/customers` or `createAccount` email sending work flow will work as described.

```
<route url="/V1/customers" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface" method="createAccount"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
```

\vendor\magento\module-customer\Model\AccountManagement.php

> createAccount -> createAccountWithPasswordHash ->
>   $this->sendEmailConfirmation($customer, $redirectUrl);

```
protected function sendEmailConfirmation(CustomerInterface $customer, $redirectUrl)
{
    try {
        $hash = $this->customerRegistry->retrieveSecureData($customer->getId())->getPasswordHash();
        $templateType = self::NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REGISTERED;
        if ($this->isConfirmationRequired($customer) && $hash != '') {
            $templateType = self::NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION;
        } elseif ($hash == '') {
            $templateType = self::NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REGISTERED_NO_PASSWORD;
        }
        $this->getEmailNotification()->newAccount($customer, $templateType, $redirectUrl, $customer->getStoreId());
    } catch (MailException $e) {
        // If we are not able to send a new account email, this should be ignored
        $this->logger->critical($e);
    }
}
```